# Error building on Open Q 820 Snapdragon 820 Hexagon 3.2 when trying to compile and link the stub and skeleton

Tags: hexagon-dsp

I am trying to run the calculator example for Hexagon DSP SDK following the instructions in `file:///C:/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.2/docs/calculator_android.html`

In the command line I have setup the sdk in the following way:

```
setup_sdk_env.cmd
```

I have cleaned and built the android module successfully

```
make tree V=android_Debug [CDSP_FLAG = 1]
```

But I have an error when trying to do it for the hexagon module.

```
make tree V=hexagon_Debug_dynamic [CDSP_FLAG = 1]
```

This is what I get:

```
C:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.2\examples\common\calculator>make tree V=hexagon_Debug_dynamic CDSP=1
making C:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.2/test/common/test_util
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
make[1]: *** [hexagon_Debug_dynamic/test_utils.o] Error 1
ERROR making C:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.2/test/common/test_util
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.2/test/common/test_util'
"C:/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.2/Tools/bin/hexagon-clang"  -mv60 -c -v -G0 -g -O0  -Wall -Werror -Wno-cast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-strict-aliasing  -fno-exceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss -fdata-sections -mllvm -disable-hsdr -fpic -D__V_DYNAMIC__ -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs      -D__FILENAME__=\"test_utils.c\" -D_DEBUG  -Iinc -Isrc -IC:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.2/incs -IC:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.2/incs/stddef -Ihexagon_Debug_dynamic  -o hexagon_Debug_dynamic/test_utils.o src/test_utils.c
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.2/test/common/test_util'
make: *** [MAKE_D_7_LIBDIR] Error 1
```

Note my computer is Spanish, "El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada." means that the system was not able to find the specified path.

Comment: Which path was it unable to find?  Is that error from `make` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

When you make the calculator and specify 'tree' the calculator's dependencies are also built.  One of which is test_utils.

Could be a number of things

- tools are missing (compiler)
- test_utils are missing
- something else...

Next step is to run the command listed in make output by itself from the test_util directory to get more information on what is missing. (`C:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.2/test/common/test_util`)

```
"C:/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.2/Tools/bin/hexagon-clang"  -mv60 -c -v -G0 -g -O0  -Wall -Werror -Wno-cast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-strict-aliasing  -fno-exceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss -fdata-sections -mllvm -disable-hsdr -fpic -D__V_DYNAMIC__ -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs      -D__FILENAME__=\"test_utils.c\" -D_DEBUG  -Iinc -Isrc -IC:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.2/incs -IC:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.2/incs/stddef -Ihexagon_Debug_dynamic  -o hexagon_Debug_dynamic/test_utils.o src/test_utils.c
```

- check that clang exists
- check that test_utils directory and required files below it exist